# Write ModelandView to a file

Tags: spring-mvc

A spring controller method returns ModelAndView and I want to write the response to a file, how can this be done ?

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(viewName);
mv.addObject("foo",foo);
return mv;
```

can the to be rendered content accessed in the same controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

The rendered view is not available at the controller level. If you need to access the rendered version in the controller, you could render the content yourself and return the rendered String from the controller method.

You could also get in further up in the stack and use a ServletFilter and wrap the output stream, e.g. with a TeeOutputStream from Apache commons. At the point you do however not really know which controller method was called. What you could do to signal this is to set a RequestAttribute in the controller method that the filter checks to decide whether to write to the file.

Comment: how to render the content ?

Comment: That depends on what mechanism you use. Spring uses a ViewResolver (which should be available as a bean) to get a View, which in Turn has a render-method.